# Mapbox change label for single point of interest

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm trying to change the label on a single subway stop. Using Mapbox studio I just can't get the tool to recognize the condition by either the point of interest ID or name. I absolutely have the ID and name correct. The screenshots are below. This is using the default streets v8 data layer. Where am I going wrong here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work:

[image: mapbox style]

You can copy my style:

https://studio.mapbox.com/styles/add-style/anatolysukhanov/ckgmtz9lq1az019qugxp1z24y/

Also, the problem might be that "The Production URL is cached for performance and scale, so new changes may take a few minutes to appear".

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, got it! Interesting, it seems that the order of the data conditions does matter regardless of how specific the condition is.

Thanks Anatoly for providing a working example for me to compare and contrast against.

[image]